# I installed the pod file for Charts and now I am getting errors while using Range

Tags: swift, charts, range, cocoapods

I installed the pod file for Charts and now the compiler is giving me errors regarding the usage of Range.

```
extension StringProtocol where Index == String.Index {
    func index(of string: Self, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> Index? {
        return range(of: string, options: options)?.lowerBound
    }
    func endIndex(of string: Self, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> Index? {
        return range(of: string, options: options)?.upperBound
    }
    func indexes(of string: Self, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> [Index] {
        var result: [Index] = []
        var startIndex = self.startIndex
        while startIndex < endIndex,
            let range = self[startIndex...].range(of: string, options: options) {
                result.append(range.lowerBound)
                startIndex = range.lowerBound < range.upperBound ? range.upperBound :
                    index(range.lowerBound, offsetBy: 1, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
        }
        return result
    }
    func ranges(of string: Self, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> [Range] {
        var result: [Range<Index>] = []
        var startIndex = self.startIndex
        while startIndex < endIndex,
            let range = self[startIndex...].range(of: string, options: options) {
                result.append(range)
                startIndex = range.lowerBound < range.upperBound ? range.upperBound :
                    index(range.lowerBound, offsetBy: 1, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

I expect no errors, however I am getting these errors that did not appear before I installed the charts library:

Reference to generic type 'Range' requires arguments in <...>

Range' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

1. Found this candidate (Swift.Range)
2. Found this candidate (Charts.Range)

Answer (score 0):

This has occurred because Charts has a Range class (as you can see [here](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/Source/Charts/Highlight/Range.swift)). I get the same compile error when using your code in a project of mine with Charts in use.

The line failing to compile (and there is only one for me) is this one:

```
func ranges(of string: Self, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> [Range] {
```

But I can fix it by simply applying the same fix you have in that func, i.e. by changing it to:

```
func ranges(of string: Self, options: String.CompareOptions = []) -> [Range<Index>] {
```

Comment: Changing it to that gives me this error: 'Range' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context Cannot specialize non-generic type 'Range' Replace '<Index>' with ''

Comment: Well that's odd because it compiles for me. Sanity check time. Make sure you're using the latest version of Xcode, and compiling with Swift 5. Do not `import Charts` into the source file with this code as that gives me (different) errors. Put this code into its own file if necessary.

Comment: can extension be put in a different while they are needed in the same file? this function is part of the string protocol extension.

Comment: Extension can go in its own file, as long as it is included in the project build.

Comment: I put it in its own file and now the errors are gone. Weird how that works if its all being built the same.

Comment: May be because of difference in imports - as I said, import Charts broke my compile. So, all good and happy with answer?